# What is the precedence between printf and ++x and x++?

Tags: c, operator-precedence

When I execute this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
int x = 10;
printf("%d  %d  %d  %d\n", ++x, ++x, ++x, ++x);
x = 10;
printf("%d  %d  %d  %d\n", x++, x++, x++, x++);
x = 10;
printf("%d  %d  %d  %d\n",++x, x++, ++x, x++);
}
```

The result is

```
14  14  14  14
13  12  11  10
14  12  14  10
```

I don't understand the sequence of operation precedence in the three  `printf` statements.

Comment: Hello, so the precedence is not only not defined, the result is not defined at all. See the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-pre-and-post-increment-undefined-behavior for explanation what it means.

Comment: This is simply undefined behavior, see [Why can't we mix increment operators like i++ with other operators?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/278384). But also it is not at all related to operator precedence, but to order of evaluation: [What is the difference between operator precedence and order of evaluation?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/278172)

Comment: @KamilCuk Operator precedence is perfectly well-defined and not at all related to this problem. See the 2nd link in my comment above.